# Tomcat application server logs are not printed in a rolling file other than catalina.log using log4j2.properties

Tags: log4j2

I have recently migrated application from log4j1.x to **log4j2.17.1**. Application logs are printed well in console as well as in Rolling file when start the tomcat server. I could see Tomcat server start up logs are all printing in catalina.log but the same server startup logs and any other server internal logs are not printed in rolling file. Rolling file prints only those logs are coming from class files. Could you anyone of you suggest what can be done to print all application server start up logs like some logs gets printed in console before server start or connection refused logs etc. also get printed into Rolling file? Same things was working well when I had log4j1.x version.It means when I had log4j1.x server start up logs are printed well in catalina as well as in a DailyRollingFileAppender but Now issue is only with log4j2, it means server start up logs are printed in catalain only not in a rolling file which I want. Please suggest.

Here is my log4j2.properties

```
rootLogger.level = info
property.filename =D:/log/TEST.log
appenders = R, console
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d %5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

appender.R.type = RollingFile
appender.R.name = File
appender.R.fileName = ${filename}
appender.R.filePattern = ${filename}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}
appender.R.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.R.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%15.15t]: %c{1}:%L - %m%n
appender.R.policies.type = Policies
appender.R.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.R.policies.time.interval = 1

rootLogger.appenderRef.console.ref = STDOUT
```

rootLogger.appenderRef.R.ref = File

Comment: Tomcat does not use Log4j 2.x as logging backend, it uses `java.util.logging` by default. Cf. [Log4j App Server Integration](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-appserver/index.html) to change this default. The reason you see all messages in `catalina.log` is that both Log4j 2.x and `java.util.logging` are configured to log to the console.

Comment: Ok Piotr. Do you have any reference link for sample codes to implement this. Could you please share?

Comment: There is nothing to implement, just follow the configuration instructions of the [link I gave before](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-appserver/index.html).